# converting .txt file into array and comparing

Tags: php, ajax

```
$eventnameentered= $_GET['eventnameentered'];
$eventnameentered= strtolower($eventnameentered);

$eventindatabase=file('eventname.txt');

if(in_array($eventnameentered,$eventindatabase)){
    echo 'Entered Event Name '.$eventnameentered.' Is Already Taken';
}else if($eventnameentered==''){
    echo 'Please Enter Name Of New Event';
}
else
{
    echo 'Event Name '.$eventnameentered.' Is Available ';
}
```

event.txt

```
gaming
coding
project
```

I'am using AJAX. Everything is working properly, I just need some help with this array thing.

I want to compare `eventname` given by user and `eventname` already present in `event.txt` do not clash. So I want `event.txt` in an array. I am comparing it with `in_array` as shown in the above code but even if I insert event present in `event.tx`t it shows `Event name Available`. I even tried using `get_file_contents`.

Comment: are the values in the file lowercased as well? `in_array()` is case-sensitive

Comment: are you sure `$eventnameentered` has expected value? echo it out

Comment: yes all values are lowere case

Comment: yes it did work :) just tried...! @Amal Murali thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace is causing your `if` condition to fail. You need to `trim` the whitespace first.

```
$eventindatabase = file('eventname.txt');
$eventindatabase = array_map('trim', $eventindatabase);
```

Here's the output of `var_dump($eventindatabase)` before and after trimming the whitespace:

Before:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "gaming
"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "coding
"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "project"
}
```

After:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "gaming"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "coding"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "project"
}
```

As you can see, the first two elements are different, and that'll cause the following condition to evaluate to `FALSE`, hence triggering the `else` statement:

```
if(in_array($eventnameentered,$eventindatabase))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: perhaps there are tabs or spaces padding the stuff in the file but there shouldn't be any newlines in the strings as shown in your example, since `file()` puts the file contents into an array based on newline chars

Comment: @CrayonViolent: It's possible to use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag, if you don't want newlines to be added at the end, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: no i'm talking about the delimiter `file()` uses to split the file into array elements. It splits it at the newline char

Comment: but i guess i didn't read hard enough. didn't know it still keeps the newline char on the end